# Catch some text from a text body in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I make a SSH connection and read the below , but I want to use some of the returned data .

**Data :** (sample 1)

```
DSL3> 7[600C[300B[6n8show lineinfo 1-2
slot-port=1-2, DSL line info
link                    : link_up
service type            : adsl2plus
coding mode             : Concatenated (trellis and RS) coding
us interleave delay(ms) : 0 ms
ds interleave delay(ms) : 0 ms
us inp(DMT Symbol)      : 0.0
ds inp(DMT Symbol)      : 0.0
us output power(dBm)    : 12.2
ds output power(dBm)    : 18.9
country code            : 00b5
provider code           : 5245544b("RETK")
DSL3>
```

**Data :** (sample 2)

```
DSL3> 7[600C[300B[6n8show lineinfo 1-3
slot-port=1-3, DSL line info
link                    : link_up
service type            : adsl2plus
coding mode             : Concatenated (trellis and RS) coding
us interleave delay(ms) : 0 ms
ds interleave delay(ms) : 0 ms
us inp(DMT Symbol)      : 0.0
ds inp(DMT Symbol)      : 0.0
us output power(dBm)    : 12.3
ds output power(dBm)    : 18.6
country code            : 0026
provider code           : 5443544e("TCTN")
DSL3>
```

**Data :** (sample 3)

```
DSL3> 7[600C[300B[6n8show lineinfo 1-8
slot-port=1-8, DSL line info
link                    : link_down
service type            : none
coding mode             : No coding
us interleave delay(ms) : 0 ms
ds interleave delay(ms) : 0 ms
us inp(DMT Symbol)      : 0.6
ds inp(DMT Symbol)      : 0.0
us output power(dBm)    : 0.0
ds output power(dBm)    : 0.0
country code            : N/A
provider code           : N/A
DSL3>
```

Line 2 until 3 
What I want to extract the status of  `link` , `service type` , `us output power(dBm)` from the returned values .

I try to do it by regex but not done .

Comment: Is these data samples are stored in a file ? (coz if u can read line 3, 4, 10 would be faster).

Comment: @Falt4rm , no this returned the values from a SSH connection , and I want to catch a the values as Variable or Array at last .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
link\s*:\s*(.*)|service type\s*:\s*(.*)|us output power\(dBm\)\s*:\s*(.*)
```

and extract `link` with `$1`, `service type` with `$2` and `us output power(dBm)` with `$3`.

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mH1wT4/3)